# React Testing Library Async Disappearance

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this pop up `Delete`, and want to check if the element is deleted after the `Confirm` button is clicked:

```
 userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('confirm-btn')) //trigger Confirm button

 waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText("Delete")).then(() =>{
    expect(screen.getByText("Item 1")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

When I change `.not.toBeInTheDocument()` to `.toBeInTheDocument();`, the test is still passed.

Why is it so? How to do it in the right way?

Comment: You don't return or await the promise chain, so the expectation is *after* the test ends. You can demonstrate this with `expect.assertions`, whose use I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64330624/3001761). Also look at the documented examples for handling async testing: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. This is how it is supposed to be:

```
userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('confirm-btn')) //trigger Confirm button

//await added. Need to add async at the start also, e.g. it("Successfully deleted", async() => ...
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText("Delete")).then(() =>{
    expect(screen.queryByText("Item 1")).not.toBeInTheDocument(); // another mistake here. 
});
```

Just to be safe, need to to have: `expect.assertions(1);` after test declaration. So that it will ensure one assertion to be called and throw error otherwise.