# Making 'expect()' mandatory for all test cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Is there a way to make the `expect()` mandatory for all test cases? If the programmer doesn't put `expect` it should throw some warning/error. I am using Jest and `@testing-library/react`.

For example:

- Should work fine:

  ```js
  test('Should work file',()=>{
      ...code...
      expect(value).toBe(expectedValue)
  })
  ```
- Should throw error/warning:

  ```js
  test('Should fail',()=>{
      ...code...
  })
  ```

Comment: There's [`expect.hasAssertions`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expecthasassertions), although you have to add that to each test, or the ESLint plugin's [`expect-expect` rule](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/master/docs/rules/expect-expect.md).

Comment: Thank you for replying eslint rule is the solution. I was referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways I'm aware of to automatically do this:

1. The ESLint Jest plugin's [`jest/expect-expect` rule](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/master/docs/rules/expect-expect.md), which will ensure that every test calls `expect` at least once. This can also be configured to allow other assertion functions/methods, like Cypress's `"cy.**.should"` or Supertest's `"request.**.assert"`.
2. Use [`expect.assertions`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber)/[`expect.hasAssertions`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expecthasassertions) *inside* the tests, so that they will fail if the required number of expectations isn't met.

   This is a bit less automated, so may not solve the problem of people forgetting to include things, but will also catch cases where assertions exist but aren't reached (e.g. due to asynchronous code or [no error being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64330421/3001761)). There's another rule in the ESLint plugin, [`jest/prefer-expect-assertions`](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-expect-assertions.md), which would check that you always use it, giving you the best of both worlds.

There's also a process-based approach: test-driven development. If you're always running the tests *before* you expect them to pass, you make sure they do indeed fail (and give useful feedback when they do so).

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer @jonrsharpe!

Answer (score 1):

Linting rules such as `jest/expect-expect` have been very useful, but I've seen `expect.hasAssertions`, placed in the shared Jest setup file, catch a few things the linter hasn't:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
   expect.hasAssertions();
});
```

The linter does a static analysis while `hasAssertions` tracks the statements executed during a test:

```js
it('should detect whether an expectation is actually run', () => {

    // Oops, we forgot the await!

    waitFor(() => {
        expect(someElement).toBeVisible();
    });

    // The waitFor essentially becomes a no-op from the point of view of
    // the test.  The test moves on and quietly passes without running  
    // an expectation.

});
```

Using `expect.hasAssertions()` also allows `jest/expect-expect` to be reconfigured slightly to allow more flexibility when abstracting expectations into helper functions, with no loss of rigour, if that's something you're interested in.

Comment: Only downside of this to note is that it only checks for _Jest_ expectations, so e.g. tests using Jest as a runner but _Supertest's_ assertions would have to be rewritten.